# html or css - vertical hr tag

Tags: html, css

I want to have a vertical line on the side and middle of my website. Is there a  `<hr />` tag that can do that, and if so can you please give it in css or html.

Answer (score 1):

"Put a div around the markup where you want the line to appear to next and use CSS to style it:" from [How to make a vertical line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line)

```
    <div class="verticalLine">

some other content

</div>
```

in css:

```
.verticalLine {
    border-left:thick solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modern browsers support `<hr style="display:inline" />` for producing a small vertical bar, but in general just `|` works better for that.

If you want a line that spans more than one line of text, you should use a border.

Answer (score 0):

There's no vertical version of `<hr/>`. What you can do is use CSS and style `border-right` or `border-left` to create a "vertical line". Here's a comprehensive article on how borders can be styled: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-refreshers-borders/