# Create dynamic vertical rule in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to create a vertical rule like the one shown at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html that updates its value dynamically according to the user's mouse.

This demo uses cubism.js but I'd like to use d3 and/or jQuery to achieve the same effect.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: I've tried creating rules according to the ones in this thread ([How to make a vertical line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line)), but I don't know how to position it and move it according to the user's mouse position.

Comment: In HTML? In SVG? What have you tried?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your question to include more detail about what you actually want, but here's one implementation using d3: http://jsfiddle.net/q3P4v/

```
d3.select('html').on('mousemove', function() {
    var xpos = d3.event.pageX;
    var rule = d3.select('body').selectAll('div.rule')
        .data([0]);
    rule.enter().append('div')
        .attr('class', 'rule')
      .append('span');
    rule.style('left', xpos + 'px');
    rule.select('span').text(xpos);
});
```

Note that this depends on some associated CSS, as shown in the fiddle.