# Create a rule in d3 using svg

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to create a dynamic vertical rule using d3.js,like the one here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html.

I asked how to create one using HTML previously here ([Create dynamic vertical rule in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198702/create-dynamic-vertical-rule-in-d3)), but the solution using HTML is not very effective over a cubism svg as it flickers and disappears.

I'd now like to create one using SVG instead.

I've tried creating one using the code here (http://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js), but I am unable to position it over existing svg and get it to update dynamically.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The existing svg is created by a d3 plugin called cubism.js, so I don't have access to the underlying svg. And while it works great by itself, this svg pushes other elements down like this (the svg line is on the left hand):

[image]
I want the rules on top of the existing graphs, that's why I mention positioning over another svg. Sorry if I didn't make that clear the first time.

Comment: You don't need to position it over the existing SVG, you can make it part of the SVG. Can you post the code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Like Lars pointed out, the bar can be part of the existing svg.

Using an svg instead of divs actually makes the code even simpler:

javascipt:

```
d3.select('#svg').on('mousemove', function() {
    var xpos = d3.event.pageX;
    d3.select('#bar').attr('x', xpos);
});
```

html:

```
<svg id="svg"width="500" height="500">
    <ellipse cx="125" cy="125" rx="125" ry="10" fill="red" />
    <rect id="bar" x="10" y="0" width="10" height="500"></rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3P4v/4/