# JQuery - assign height of container (parent) div to child element (vertical bar)

Tags: jquery, siblings, outerheight

I am new to jQuery. I have a repeating div (.containingBox) which has three internal divs (.summary0, .summary1, .summary2) which hold the data. After summary0 and before summary2 I would like to show a vertical bar. This bar's height should be set dynamically. The value will be taken from the 'outerHeight' of 'containingBox' after the summary divs have filled up with data.

```
.containingBox {
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #C8C8C8;
    margin: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
.summary0 {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%; 
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, OptimaLTStdBold;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 10px;
}

.summary1 {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, OptimaLTStdBold;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 10px;
}

.summary2 {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%; 
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, OptimaLTStdBold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px; 
}

.vLine {
    background-color:grey; 
    width:1px; 
    float:left;
    height:100px; 
 }

<div class="vLine"></div>
```

The vertical line works when hard coded ([How to make a vertical line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line)). So far I have done the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".containingBox0").each(function(){
        txt = $(this).outerHeight();
        $(this).siblings(".vLine").css('height', txt);        
    });
});
```

The central problem is the last line of jquery. There are two .vLine in  container div but I can't get the assignment to work. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9Wshe/

Comment: Please update the fiddle I appended to your question with HTML that includes .containingBox0 and any other required elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't assign the value to a jquery selector that returns multiple elements.
you have to change the line that reads:

```
$(this).children(".hrLine").css('height', txt);
```

to something like;

```
$(this).children(".hrLine").each(function(){
   $(this).css('height', txt);
});
```

tell me if this works for you

Update: changed `$(this).siblings` to `$(this).children`

Comment: Made your amendment but can't get to work. I see your point though about multiple elements.

Comment: Solved. It should be 'children' not 'siblings'. Also changed '.vLine' height attribute to 100%. Finally got there.