# Styling border-right?

Tags: css, menu, line

I'm working on a left navigation menu, and I need a vertical line to separate the menu from the main content of the page. Now I am using the skeleton framework which includes a custom hr tag that looks great, I have one placed just beneath the title.

However when I use border-right on my menu the line is a bland black line (otherwise unstyled hr tag).

How do I style border-right to look like the Skeleton hr tag?
Or should I be using a custom styled div to make a better looking vertical line?

Here's the code for the styled hr:

```
hr { border: solid #ddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 10px 0 30px;    height: 0; }
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: can you provide some snaps on your desired output, or maybe a fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a vertical line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line)

Comment: I was under this assumption that you want to use an `<hr>` element to do so. I'll respectfully delete my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be use `border-right:1px solid #000000;` for right border. Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/ZxHm4/)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Appreciate all the responses to my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can style the `border-right` the same way you styled the `hr`

```
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
```