# How do I put vertical lines between a list of text?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

here is what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQCFD.png

I'm having trouble aligning everything like that and was looking for some help. I would alos like it centered. Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<p class="aboutus">
<b>About Us</b><br>
<br>   
NECI Overview<br>
Our History<br>
Accreditation<br>
Why choose us?<br>
Campus Tour<br>
Affliations<br>
Awards<br>
Community <br>
News<br>
</p>

<hr width="1" size="190" align="left">
```

CSS:

```
.aboutus{

font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line

Answer (score 0):

Another [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h7TNu/).

CSS

```
.myinfo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.myinfo:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```