# Vertical Line in CSS that doesn't take up the whole border

Tags: html, css

I read this article: [How to make a vertical line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html)
but the height style didn't work for `<th>` tags

My CSS is like this:

```
.verticalLine
{
    width: 1px;
    background-color: Black;
    height: 10px;
}
```

My HTML is this:

```
<th class="verticalLine"></th>
```

Unfortunately, the vertical line spans the whole border.  I have tried percentages instead of pixels, to no avail.

Edited

`.navCenter
    {
        text-align:center;
        display:table-cell;
    }`

`<nav style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 70%; height:55px;">
     <table>
     <tr class="navCenter">
     <th><h2><a href="Home.aspx" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue;"><img src="Pictures/BartleHallToppers.jpg" height="42px" width="100px"/></a></h2></th>
     <th class="verticalLine"></th>
     <th><h2><a href="Events.aspx" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Events</a></h2></th>
     <th><h2><a href="" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Restaurants</a></h2></th>
     <th><h2><a href="" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Hotels</a></h2></th>
     <th><h2><a href="" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Points of Interest</a></h2></th>
     <th><h2><a href="" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Public Works</a></h2></th>
     <th><h2><a href="" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Road Construction</a></h2></th>
     <th><h2><a href="FAQ.aspx" style="padding: 2px; color: Blue; text-decoration: none;">Contact Us</a></h2></th>
     </tr>
     </table> 
     </nav>`

Comment: Why are you using the `th` element instead of the `div` element as shown in the SO answer that you referred to?

Comment: Yes.  I'm creating a Nav Menu and I would like to have that vert line in between the menu items

Comment: Can you post the rest of the HTML, tables tend to be tricker to deal with, thanks.

Comment: Using Table to create a nav menu? That's new to me. Seriously avoid using tables for layout purposes.

Comment: May I ask why?  They actually seem easy to manipulate (until this problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using tables is not a good practice for creating a navigation

you can `ul` `li` and for border `pseudo`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6kdws7h/)

```
li:not(:last-child):after {
    content:"|";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

or

```
li:not(:last-child):after {
    content:" ";
    width:1px;
    position:absolute;
    border-right:1px solid;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tables for creating nav menu is not a best practic, but your code must works, if you put `th` into `table`:

```css
.verticalLine
{
    width: 1px;
    background-color: Black;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <th class="verticalLine"></th>
</table>
```

`