# Why I can't halve div with vertical line

Tags: html, css

I have one big container, and inside I have two div, I want to separate these internal divs with vertical line, I posted down what I tried, on another example thats CSS code work correctly, but in this case not working.
HTML

```
<div class="rowFrame"> 
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Info:</h3>
        <p>About</p>
        <p>About</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 rightcontact" >
         <h3>Contact us</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .container2{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
   }

.rowFrame{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: If you want a vertical line between the two chidren you would be better to use a border on one of those.

Comment: Also I tried that, but without success.
For the right children div I set class "rightcontact" and in CSS write this code:

.rightcontact{
 border-style: solid;
    border-left: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Perhaps you could demo the problem...I'm not sure why you need `display:inline-block` though.

Comment: @Paulie_D
This is ilustrationhttp://i.imgur.com/8CszdD7.png . picture 1 is how to look after this code:
.rightcontact{ border-style: solid; border-left: 3px;  }
I want to make like picture 2

Comment: Can't diagnose a picture...we need the actual HTML & CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a vertical line in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html)

Comment: @Paulie_D
I don't understand thats accepted answer, look at jsfiddle thats answer
http://jsfiddle.net/phcjmqk2/
this is my jsfiddle html and css http://jsfiddle.net/2pjoo19e/1/

Comment: So where is the vertical line supposed to be and what purpose does it serve? In other words...what is the **result** supposed to look like?

Comment: @Paulie_D I using bootstrap, and on jsfiddle not show correctly.
I wan't to make like this, i wan't to put this vertical line before senteces "Kontaktirajte nas"
http://i.imgur.com/boCVuWl.png
Thank you man!

Comment: You're using the wrong column classes i suspect...those are usually for mobile.

Comment: @Paulie_D Those would be the right classes. Bootstrap cascades upward. So if you have col-sm-6, that will also translate to col-md-6 and col-lg-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a vertical line between the two divs? Just add a border to one of the two divs. If you want full width you need to make your container fluid. Here is an example showing both full width and normal container.

**full width example (fluid container)**

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/DTcHh/5519/)

html

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="mycontainer">
  <div class="col-sm-6" id="one">
    <h3>Info:</h3>
    <p>Ukoliko imate neko pitanje budite slobodni i pitajte nas!</p>
    <p>Podelite sa nama Vase misljenje.</p>
  </div>



  <div class="col-sm-6" id="two" >
    <h3>Kontaktirajte nas</h3>
      some text here... bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#mycontainer{
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#one{
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

**normal container**

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/DTcHh/5520/)

html

```
<div class="container" id="mycontainer">
  <div class="col-sm-6" id="one">
    <h3>Info:</h3>
    <p>Ukoliko imate neko pitanje budite slobodni i pitajte nas!</p>
    <p>Podelite sa nama Vase misljenje.</p>
  </div>



  <div class="col-sm-6" id="two" >
    <h3>Kontaktirajte nas</h3>
      some text here... bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#mycontainer{
    border:1px solid black;
}

#one{
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: hohoho thank you man, thats it. Too short and great.
Can you explain me what is : overflow: hidden;

Comment: I'm glad I helped! You need `overflow: hidden;` on the fluid container to get it's height matching the content height. Remove the style in the example to see what I mean.

Comment: Hey man, I have problem with your code, when I added more paragraphs and tags in child divs I have problem with vertical line, line is not full height, look picture http://i.imgur.com/vpfzmHe.png
here is and  code jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c01nmn3k/

Comment: Just give div two a left border and remove the right border of div one.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes but here's a basic example of what you can do:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">
    <h3>Info:</h3>
    <p>Ukoliko imate neko pitanje budite slobodni i pitajte nas!</p>
    <p>Podelite sa nama Vase misljenje.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <h3>Kontaktirajte nas</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  #container {
    height: 500px;
    border: medium black solid;
  }
  #container div {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  #one {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border-right: thin black solid;
  }
  #two {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: thin black solid;
  }
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgwgOm)

Comment: Check my latest edit. You'll have to change the height in #container to add more text.

Comment: Try now. I took out the bootstrap classes though.

Answer (score 0):

If you do what @primeape91 is suggesting you'll also need to include the [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) hack to get the float to act like a block again.

```
div.rowFrame:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

div.rowFrame > div {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
```