# How to make vertical line in css

Tags: css

How to make this footer? example in this foto
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html

Comment: but i need 3 in one div?

Comment: You can set "border-left:1px solid #000" to your divs css

Comment: You will need multiple divs to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you working with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

If you must, you can do it using a background image with fixed lines.

If you want to do it the right way, you'll definitely need multiple divs to do that. Here's one way:

```css
.column{
  width:30%;
  height:100px;
  padding:1.5%;
  float:left;
  border-right:1px solid grey;
}

.column:last-child{
border-right: none;
}

.footer{
  border:1px solid grey;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">

  <div class="column" >
    blah
  </div>
  
  <div class="column" >
    blah
  </div>

  <div class="column" >
    blah
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of. You'd need to customise the code around it to suit the responsive design you require.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrnzn4t2/).

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
  border-left: solid 2px #cdcdcd;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
<div style="background-color: green; width: 100%;float: right">
    <div style="width: 20% ;height: 90px; border-left: 2px solid #000;float: right">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 20% ;height: 90px; border-left: 2px solid #000;float: right">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 20% ;height: 90px; border-left: 2px solid #000;float: right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a bad habit using in-line CSS

Answer (score 0):

Firt you add class in to these three divs..

```
<div class='border'>AAAA</div>
<div class='border'>BBB</div>
<div class='border'>CCC</div>
```

then you add css part

```
.border{

border-left: solid 2px #cdcdcd;

}
```

you arrange margins also...

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem.try this and try the preview with full page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

div.myfooter{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#81C41D; 
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div.one{
  width:35%;
  height:100%;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
div.two{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  text-align: center;
}
div.three{
  width: 22.5%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  text-align: center;
}

div.four
{
   width: 26.5%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 72.5%;
  text-align: center;

}

</style>
<body>

<div class="myfooter">
 <div class="one"><h3>Section One</h3></div>
 <div class="two"><h3>Sectioin Two</h3></div>
 <div class="three"><h3>Section Three</h3></div>
 <div class="four"><h3>Section Four</h3></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using css3, here's your solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer div { display: block; float: left; background: #eee; height: 220px; width: 33%; }
#footer div:not(:first-child) { border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6zto4dg5/