# HTML code for separating text with line

Tags: javascript, css, html

i need to add vertical line between text in HTML or JavaScript

the description for what i need exactly its explain with this picture

[image: i need like this pic]

how to add line before CHECKPOINT and FINAL like in the pic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html

Comment: thanks for answer ...but this solution not work for me ...its not give me like i need :)

Comment: The suggested answer is perfectly good. If there's a reason it doesn't work in your code you need to let us know about that. Otherwise, please read the linked answer closely, understand how it works, and consider how to apply that to your situation.

Comment: Is CSS allowed?

Comment: @user2314737 I challenge you to do it without

Comment: @Purag I guess not

Comment: If you don't like first answer from linked question I would recommend using border-right or border-left in your CSS (you can also find this solution in linked question). For me this is usually the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
li {
 line-height:100px;
 width:100px;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}
ul li:last-child {
 border-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li{
border:0px solid #ddd;
border-right:2px solid #ddd;
}
ul li:last-child{
border:0;
```

html

```
<ul type=none>
<li> menu1</li>
<li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfpe31ba/)