# How do I get the submenu to not disappear?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, header

I have a navigation menu on my website. It works, however when hovering over a menu item with sub-items they disappear when trying to click on them. It appears that there is a spacing issue with these items.

*Additionally, I am trying to figure out how to insert a | between the menu items. If you could share some insight that would be amazing. I only have basic coding knowledge as you can probably tell from my post.

I appreciate the assistance!

```css
/* do not change */

.container {
  overflow: unset;
}

#container ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}


/* can change */

#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#container ul li {
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#container ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

#container ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #1dcdfe;
}

#container ul li:hover ul li {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#scroll-home'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#scroll-whyhere'>Why You're Here</a></li>
        <li><a href='#scroll-ourmethod'>Our Method</a></li>
        <li><a href='#scroll-whyus'>Why Choose US</a></li>
        <li><a href='#scroll-testimonials'>Testimonials</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Our Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#scroll-wetreat'>What We Treat</a></li>
        <li><a href='#scroll-packages'>Packages & Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#scroll-faq'>FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want horizontal separators on your top-most navigation elements.

To do this, you can add borders to your `li` elements and then exclude the last one, like so:

```
#container ul li {
  // ... other styles here
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/* Add this additional style so that the last item doesn't receive the border */
#container ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

A working example can be found at https://codepen.io/BrandonClapp/pen/wvGqrmQ

Answer (score 0):

Following code add the pipes between menu's

```
#container > ul > li {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#container > ul > li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thats because you have given every `li` a specific height here:

```
#container ul li {
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Which does not let the box grow when its hovered. You can give the nav buttons that have the hovering option an id and give the following code:

```
#container ul li #drop_down{
  height: 100%;
}
```

For hindering future confusion, if you want to select direct children, use `>`, like so:

```
#container > ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here you have not used it, so even the inner `ul` is having these attributes, which ruins it. If you change it to the code above it will get fixed. Why? because the inner `ul` has the `display: inline-block;` attribute in your code which should not be.

Furthermore, Try giving the box a `background-color` and a `z-index`, so it will not keep detecting hover in behind boxes, in this case contact button.

For your other question I refer you to this link:
[How to make a vertical line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html)

And, or:
https://medium.com/@hollybourneville/creating-border-lines-using-pseudo-elements-in-css-a460396299e8