# Crossing lines in html/twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I tried some of the answers posted on this forum but cannot find one fitting for me,

I realise this is an age old question sorry.

Im trying to get a vertical line like in this design:

[image: Design]

The problem i'm facing is that this is in a table and I cannot figure out how to get them to cros like this.

Its about the element td with 'scores' id

**Twig file**

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="table-responsive">
        {% for group in duel_groups %}
            {% if group is not empty %}
        <table class="table table-bordered table-light" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Omloop</th>
                <th>Partuur 1</th>
                <th>Scores</th>
                <th>Partuur 2</th>
{#                <th>Spelers</th>#}
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-center">
            {% for duel in group %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ duel.omloopNummer }}</td>


                    <td id="team1">{{ duel.team1 }}</td>


                    <td id="scores">
                        {{ duel.eerstenP1 }} {{ duel.eerstenP2 }}<br>
                        <hr>
                        {{ duel.puntenP1 }} {{ duel.puntenP2 }}
                    </td>
                    


                    <td id="team2">{{ duel.team2 }}</td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

I have tried creating a div of 1px but that didn't work.
I tried a couple of solutions from this question [How to make a vertical line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html)

None seem to fit my use case tho.

Comment: Have you styles that you have created to try to achieve this? Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, you are trying to make a cross from vertical lines? Did you try using CSS to achieve your goal? It might be helpful to abstract the HTML, so it can be run here as a snipped example, omitting the twig specific template code.

Comment: I posted a picture of what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Reason #9364 why you shouldn't use tables for anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around some more came up with this:

```
<td id="scores" style="background: linear-gradient(#bcbcbd, #bcbcbd) no-repeat center/3px 85%;"> 
       {{ duel.eerstenP1 }} {{ duel.eerstenP2 }}<br>
           <hr style="border-top: 3px solid #000000; background: transparent;">
       {{ duel.puntenP1 }} {{ duel.puntenP2 }}
</td>
```

Where I am adding a vertical line to the middle of the column and styling the hr tag