# Vertical hr tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there anything like an hr tag, but in a vertical sense?

I don't want to use a table but basically I have two tabs and I want a line between the headers of the tabs.

Here's a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tprats108/r7rzt/14/) of it.

Edit: New version of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7rzt/40/) using border-right

Edit: [Close enough!](http://jsfiddle.net/r7rzt/50/) But if I put padding-top = 10 in friendsH and familyH instead of header, it works perfectly for some reason but then the things aren't centered vertically so I think i prefer it this way

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295558/vertical-rule-as-opposed-to-hr-in-css) seems like a hack way to do it, but if it's the only way then i guess this is just the same question.

Comment: You'd be best off using the CSS border property

Comment: Either use border or, if the elements are a different height and you want it to match the tallest, I have a jQuery function I've written to do so. Let me know if you want it.

Comment: would it work to reach down to the hr tag?  Cuz in the updated jsfiddle i'm using the border and it doesn't quite make it.  I explicitly set width and height of the box.

Comment: You'll likely need to fiddle with the padding, margin & height properties so that it covers the full height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Vertical" hr tag. You can use "border-left" and "border-right" css properties to get such an effect.

Comment: it almost works but looks a little odd that it doesn't reach the hr line below it.  Any idea how to fix that? I updated the fiddle

Comment: may be use "border-bottom" instead of hr tag

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. `<hr style="display: inline" />` will result in a vertical rule.

(Fails in IE7, though, so you might want to conditional-comment a style to hide it or replace it with `|` instead)

Comment: _"replace it with `|`"_ ? can you elaborate on that? plz

Comment: this sort of worked but i couldn't get it to adjust to the height i needed

Comment: Well, in my case, I like to put `<span class="vr">|</span>`, and then use a conditional-reveal comment `<!--[if IE gt 7]>--> ... <!--<![endif]-->` to include a script that replaces `span.vr` with a "vertical rule"... So in other words I do it the other way around, to provide a better experience for old browser users.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything native to HTML.  You can create something using CSS, using a very narror div for example with either a border on only one side, or an image background.  If you're using jquery you may find a plugin to do it, but it would probably have more functionality such as allowing the user to drag and resize the divided areas.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tprats108/r7rzt/14/

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that I picked up lately, that will make a vertical `<hr>`:

```
<hr width="1" size="500" style="display:inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no vertical hr tag, however you can use css to make a vertical hr

```css
.vhr {
  width: 1px;
  height: 200px;

  }
```

```html
<div class="v-hr"></div>
```