# Why can't I center this image within the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my image inside the div, but its seemingly glued to the right.

Here are my divs:

```
<div align="left" style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:210px;">
        <img src="res/img/TopAd.png" style="top:-100px; padding:10 0 10 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: image in div]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try left: 50% ! or display:block;  margin:auto;

Comment: On which element? @ZeRuBuES

Comment: that's not going to work, the `left` property only applies to an element set to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`

Comment: display:block; margin:auto; is the solution to this case

Comment: That img needs alt text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`img` tags are `inline` by default so all you have to do is call `text-align: center` on its parent:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <div style="width:210px;text-align: center;">
    <img src="res/img/TopAd.png" style="padding:10px 0;">
  </div>
</div>
```

A few other notes:

1. You can remove `align="left"`, that's not supported in HTML5.
2. You can also remove  `top: -100px` because the `top`, `left`, `right`, and  `bottom` properties don't work unless an element is set to `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`.
3. This line: `padding: 10 0 10 0;` is missing `px` added to it and can be condensed to `padding: 10px 0;` which is top and bottom.

**UPDATE**

if you want to just center all of this in the middle of the page you can add `text-align: center` to the `body` but I would suggest removing the first `div` and adding `margin:auto` to the second one which has a defined width:

```
<div style="width:210px;text-align: center; margin: auto;">
   <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/400" style="padding:10px 0;"/>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezw7fsy2/1/)

Comment: it's hard to tell what the issue actually is, because from this code there is nothing to center. If you just want to center all of this in the middle of the page then set `body{ text-align: center}`

Comment: @zachgates can you explain a little more what's supposed to happen? It appears that this isn't as clear as it seemed to be

Comment: @zachgates I'm glad you got it working. Out of curiosity, can you explain what you mean by `I adjusted the vertical line to the left`?

Comment: The vertical line was made using something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571900/is-there-a-vr-vertical-rule-in-html). I adjusted the width of the line to 0px, and changed my image to match the above. @jmore009

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="left"
```

The `align` attribute was deprecated in HTML4.  Use `style="text-align: left;"` instead of `align="left"`.

```
padding:10 0 10 0;
```

10 of what?  You are missing the units.  You probably want `10px` for pixels:

```
padding:10px 0 10px 0;
```

I don't see any code in there that even looks like it's trying to center the image.  Try `text-align: center` on the container that the image should be centered within.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:210px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/160/160" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zachgates - I've added a code snippet that demonstrates an image centered within a div.  Please edit your question, including enough code to reproduce the problem you are experiencing.  A code snippet that reproduces your problem is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="left" style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:210px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
        <img src="res/img/TopAd.png" style="top:-100px; padding:10 0 10 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the task.

```
<div align="left" style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:210px;" align="center">
    <img src="res/img/TopAd.png" style="top:-100px; padding:10 0 10 0;">
</div>
```