# hr elements vertically between buttons?

Tags: html, css

I need to get an hr element in between 2 buttons so that it is vertically centered in between them.

This is my codepen, I've been struggling to find a decent solution. Could anybody please take a quick look?

Right now they are below and above.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpvwvv

```
<button class="left">Test</button>
<hr />
<button class="right">Test</button>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one. I recommend that you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571900/is-there-a-vr-vertical-rule-in-html

Comment: hr means `horizontal rule`. If you want vertical divider. Check the answers below.

Comment: Do you want something like [THIS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVQRow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this was the solution that you were looking for but I made a pen with the hr 'joining the two buttons'.

The easiest way is to use absolute positioning as that allows the buttons to be dynamic, like this:

```
hr {
position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGYEyE

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: This is what I mean yeah. It just needs a little padding so it doesn't touch the buttons completely though. Kind of like it's floating between them. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

`hr` element is supposed to be used horizontally talking in semantically. Instead of `hr` element you can use an `span` element. But why do you create unnecessary element while you can make this without needing any element. You can just apply a border on `button` element.

**example:**

```
button.left{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Alternatively, you could set `border-left` for the right button too.

By the way, it's not recommend way to use still while talking in semantic. You should use `div` for the layout and inside that div put your button elements and apply the border on div.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be one. But you can do something like: `<div style="border-left:1px solid #000;height:500px"></div>`