# How to add this vertical divider in navbar?

Tags: css

[image]

I need to create this kind of divider (the vertical line before browse and avatar). I don't want to use images, so is there a way to make in css?

I have tried:

```
.hr_v {
    width: 1px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    color: gray;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The css shall be applied on the floated div, not a `hr` tag.

`hr` cannot be applied vertically [Is there a vr (vertical rule) in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571900/is-there-a-vr-vertical-rule-in-html).

You need to only set the border-left and add the border color since it was missing in your code, you can also add a left padding for better view :

```
#floatingAvatarDiv
{    
   border-left: 1px solid gray;
   padding-left: 2px;
}
```

or create a class since you need it for both divs :

```
.leftBorderDiv
{    
       border-left: 1px solid gray;
       padding-left: 2px;
}
```

and add it to your menu container and the avatar container divisions

Comment: but i cant add the space between div and the border, right?

Comment: sure you can, that's what the padding is for, If you can post your html i can give you a snippet to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :before

```
.avatar {
position: relative;
height: 80px;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
.avatar:before {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 1px;
content: '';
width: 1px;
background-color: #333; /* different gray */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your "Browse" button's container is bigger, you may get longer borders. In such case, you may simply try a "|" (a pipe) in a span before the "Browse" button and style to however you want. In this case, you wont have to use a lot of css styling.