# How to place a vertical hr line beside two images in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an website page which has one large header photo, an horizontal line underneath and two images. Beside these images I would like to add one vertical hr line which displays an indent. I have tried to do this but it just disorientates my code and doesn't work. I have looked into this problem but have found no resources online at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.img1 {
    min-width: 100%;    
}

 .bikeimg {
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
 }

 .bike {
    text-align: center;
 }

 .coins {
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -8px;
 }

 .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin-top: -320px;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }

.hr_first {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

</style>

<body>

<img src="backgroundfirsttry.jpg" class="img1" height=483>

 <div class="title">Our Proposals</div>

 <hr size="30" color="black" class="hr_first">

 <img src="bikeimg.jpg" class="bikeimg">

 <hr size="5" color="black" height="500">   

 <img src="recycling.jpg" class="coins">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: there is no vertical hr, use a div with a border instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571900/is-there-a-vr-vertical-rule-in-html

Comment: Ok. I tried adding that previously but it wasn't working as well. Can you incorporate it into the code. Sorry to bother you. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: To be clear as @Isac pointed out, `<hr>` doesn't stand for "horizontal rule" for nothing.

Comment: Yes, I understand this concept now. I had seen a question before which had given that understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced your `hr` with a `div`, and adjusted the widths of the images so that the `div` would fit. 
Also the border solution didn't work here due to your percentage widths, which would get more than 100% size and push the second image down.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.img1 {
    min-width: 100%;    
}

 .bikeimg {
    width: 49.9%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
 }

 .bike {
    text-align: center;
 }

 .coins {
    width: 49.9%;
    height: 350px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -8px;
 }

 .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin-top: -320px;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }

.vertical-hr {
 margin-top: -8px;
 width:0.2%;
 height: 350px;
 float:left; 
 background-color:black;
}
.hr_first {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

</style>

<body>

<img src="backgroundfirsttry.jpg" class="img1" height=483>

 <div class="title">Our Proposals</div>

 <hr size="30" color="black" class="hr_first">

 <img src="bikeimg.jpg" class="bikeimg">
 
 <div class="vertical-hr"></div>

 <img src="recycling.jpg" class="coins">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Looks great. I have tried to make the vertical line thicker but it isn't working. I can change the image sizes that isn't important. Just need to clearly show that they are separated. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: And the original hr disappears for some reason

Comment: Try running it locally, i can see it on my browser in the local file, just doesn't seem to be appearing at the live snippet

Comment: I just did. The horizontal  line reappers

Comment: Can you just make the vertical one more thicker and visible. I have tried to do it but won't work

Comment: Just adjust the vertical line width, and reduce the images width accordingly

Comment: I understand that. But it will not run when I adjust it at the current moment

Comment: How so? what does it show? Try setting the vertical line width to 0.4% and both images width to 49.8% as an example. That would make it thicker

Comment: Nothing happens for some reason

Comment: Nevermind. I have the problem figured out. Thanks so much for the help